# How do I use two NStableviews on the same interface?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I am re-phrasing an earlier question and re-posting. I made the original question too complicated; I understand how the set up a TableView and get files to drop into it. What I don't understand is; How do I get two NSTableViews on one interface and get the contents to display in what ever table I choose? For eample, I want to drag files/folders into the first TableView, and when I double click on one, I want the contents of the file/folder to display in the second table.

Thanks

Comment: Please specify how you are providing data to the table view(s) that are implemented so far: are you using the `NSTableViewDataSource` protocol methods (`numberOfRowsInTableView:` and `tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:`), or are you using bindings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide the two table views with two different dataSource delegates, or, in the single dataSource object observe the UITableView address that's passed on every call.

Comment: I realized today there were some methods I wasn't aware of; You can use if statements inside the TableView method to find out which tableView is calling and the you can populate the table with some call[] and then you just call like [tableView3 refreshData] or something like that in some other function. Thank you for your post

Comment: Glad you figured it out -- shows you have some talent at this.  Far too many would demand to be shown the exact code needed.